# JS Doc: How to define the object returned by a javascript es6 class as a custom type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have somewhat of the following code:

```js
export class Logger {
   constructor(label = null, options = {}) {
      if (!winston.loggers.has(label)) {
         winston.loggers.add(
            label,
            { /* ...default options */ }
         );
      }

      return winston.loggers.get(label);
   }

   // some other function...
}
```

Here, my class returns a custom object which is a Winston logger object. But when I import this class in my other files and create a new object with it (`const logger = new Logger()`), the auto-suggestion show only the function in the class i.e `// some other function`.
Now, since my class returns a Winston logger instance, I want to be able to document it with JS doc so that I get my auto-suggestion back.

Is there a way I can achieve this with JS doc, to define a custom type of object that an already defined class returns?

Answer (score 0):

are you using typescript compiler? If then you can define a `logger.types.ts` types file and import it in jsdoc returns annotation.

```
/**
 * Logger Component of the form
 * @returns {import("./logger.types.ts").LoggetProps}
 */

export interface LoggetProps extends winston {
     //example props
     isError: boolean


}
```

Comment: No. I'm only using Javascript

Comment: @Kiran Check this out
https://hectane.com/blog/type-checking-in-javascript-files